# Auto filling multiple text boxes based on selected dropdown list item

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have two tables product and customer. I am creating a billing page based on the values in these two tables. for billing I have created a view. In this view there are text boxes which should auto filled based on the selected dropdown list item.

**view**

```
<div class="d-flex ">
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label class="control-label">Bill No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control">
</div>


<div class="col-lg-3 ml-auto">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("customer", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Customer, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control dropdownlist", @onclick="phone()"})</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label class="control-label">Phone No.</label>
    <input id="phn" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">Item Name</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("product", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Products, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control dropdownlist", @onchange="prodt(this)" })</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">Rate</label>
    <input id="rate" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">GST%</label>
    <input id="gst" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">Stock</label>
    <input id="stock" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label class="control-label">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**in this view *rate,gst and stock should auto filled based on the selected dropdown item in product dropdown list*** .

**Controller**

```
     public IActionResult Billing()
    {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
        var cus = db.GetAllCustomer();
        var prd = db.GetAllProducts();
        ViewBag.Customer = new SelectList(cus, "Phone", "CustomerName");
        ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(prd, "ProductID", "ProductName");
        return View();
    }
```

*controller for ajax*

```
  public ActionResult Getselectedprdct(int id)
    {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
        var productdetails = db.GetProduct(id);
        return Json(productdetails);
    }
```

*java script and ajax used*

```
 function prodt() {
    var Id = $('#dasa').val();
if (Id > 0) {
    window.location.href = '/Billing/Getselectedprdct?id=' + Id;
} };




  $(document).ready(function(){
 new updatetext();});

 function updatetext () {
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '@Url.Action("Getselectedprdct", "Billing")',
     datatype: "Json",
     success: function (data) {
         $("#rate").val(data);
         //$("#gst").val(data.GST);
         //$("#stock").val(data.Stock);

         }
     });
  };
```

***Using this ajax code I can get the data but it reloading another page . What I need is to update the billing page text boxes without reloading the page***

**Product Model**

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public Int64 Rate { get; set; }
    public float GST { get; set; }
    public string Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a partial view model and on change hit an event to return a new row with all of the details necessary.

Comment: @Drewskis, yes like that, but the returning values after hitting the event is the data from the data base table

Comment: I will create an answer when I have more time but to sum it up: You will create a new model (say ProductLinePartialViewModel) that holds the details of the product from a new command say db.GetProductInfo(product_id) and a controller action that returns a PartialView("_ProductLine") called after change() is fired in jquery.